# Query for date part of date_time field. yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to find if there is a post from the same date.

```
@selected_date = Date.new(params["post"]["date(1i)"].to_i,params["post"]["date(2i)"].to_i,params["post"]["date(3i)"].to_i)

@existing_post = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id, date: @selected_date).first
```

My `@selected_date` contains only the date **2021-03-19**, but my date db field contains time as well `date: "2021-03-19 17:43:50.640258000 +0000"`

In the Query how can I point only date section to compare? When I do `, date: @selected_date)` its trying to compare without time, so it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`all_day`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_day) helper which creates a range covering the whole day.

```rb
Post.find_by(user_id: current_user.id, date: @selected_date.all_day)
```

Comment: Awesome! This works! I didn't know there was such a method! This is the thing with Ruby on Rails, there are SOOO MANY methods, it is hard to know or find something that may work for your need.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways of doing it:

1. Honor the DB type, and query accordingly:

```rb
@existing_post = Post.where(
 user_id: current_user.id, 
 date: @selected_date.beginning_of_day..@selected_date.end_of_day # use @selected_date.all_day from Eyeslanduc's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787291/299774
).first
```

This will query for entries with `date` between the day's 00:00:00 and 23:59:59

2. Cast the `date` column, which seems to be really a timestamp:

```rb
@existing_post = Post
  .where(user_id: current_user.id) 
  .where("date_trunc('day', date)::date = ?", @selected_date).first
```

possibly `.where("date::date = ?", @selected_date)` would work the same.

This would cast the `date` column to `date` type, which should give you what you want.